What is the differences training syllabus for a Microlight rating to an SSEA rating?
Have looked around for this, but struggling to find the answer.
I have an NPPL (UK) license with a Microlight rating. I want to get the SSEA rating so I can fly 4 seat aircraft without basically starting again with a PPL.
How much training is required and what additional theory or practical exams are there if any?

To add an SSEA rating you need to complete a minimum of 3 hours training covering 2 hours slow flight and stalls and 1 hour instrument appreciation.
However, saying this you also need to get familiar with flying the heavier aircraft, i.e. a Eurofox so it normally takes between 8-10 hours.
Also a practical navigation skills test and a general skills test.
In terms of theory, you need to pass the PPL Principles of Flight exam and the PPL Aircraft General exam.

Links to the sources of this info would improve the answer for future visitors

Hey @Jamiec, I got this as an email response from a local flight school
